# Scheduling each requests in a jmeter threadgroup

Tags: request, load, jmeter

I want to start each request in a threadgroup at different times.Is it possible in jmeter? that is suppose there are 50 requests.each request should start at different times after the thread group started.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the thread group at specific time. Once the thread group is started,  you can use only `timers` to delay the requests inside the thread group. You can not actually schedule it!!

Comment: ok..if i have the starting times of various threads stored in a file,can i use an if controller and check the current time with the time stored in the file and start the request.

Comment: Instead of time, can you not use delay? Or can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: my objective is like , initiallly i will sent a request to a server. then i will extract the response.The response will contain a "wait time" and "another url". Then i will wait for the specified "wait time" and then again send the request to the new url specified in the response. one option is like as u specified. give the waittime as the delay..it worked..but if i am giving the delay the thread will still be alive..i want to avoid that....